# How can I delete the first word from a line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Mon 25-Jul-2011
```

I want to delete the first word "Mon" with javascript jQuery.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you don't want to split the string (faster, less memory consumed), you can use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) with [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
var original = "Mon 25-Jul-2011";
var result = original.substr(original.indexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Comment: would using `original.split(' ').pop();` be faster if we only want the last item to be result?

Comment: @Cristus, you still have to tokenize the entire string and to build an array with the tokens, just to access the last one. `pop()` will also mutate that array (it will remove the item it returns) for nothing. So I don't think it would be faster, no.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it overlooks the fact that the string may contain an extra trailing whitespace in the front of the string, thereby making this a wrong solution. You need to trim extra whitespaces.

Comment: @Aleksandr, it is pretty hard to evaluate all the things that can be "overlooked" when answering a question with a specific context. Yes, there could be leading whitespace (although there isn't in this specific question), or the space characters could be something other than "normal" spaces (non-breaking, thin, narrow, en, em, etc.), or something else. I usually try to stick to the question's perimeter, otherwise I would end up with huge answers and dilute the parts that readily addresses the questions.

Comment: Fair enough, though I can't imagine that there could be any other things you'd have to account for if we're just dealing with strings, aside from the possibility of leading whitespace (which is an easy fix). Just wanted to point it out for a more "comprehensive" solution.

Comment: I should add that, when there's only one word in the string (with no spacing), nothing is mutated - if you want an empty string returned, you can instead do `original.substr(original.indexOf(" ") + 1 || original.length)`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This answer is ambiguous w.r.t. "faster, less memory consumed."  I believe the answer represents the faster and smaller memory consumption of the two options.  But the sentence appears to read otherwise.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to remove first word from each items in Array of strings. I did that using `split`, `slice`, `join`.

```
var str = "Mon 25-Jul-2011"
var newStr = str.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
console.log(str)
```

Run this code in console you will get the expected string.

Answer (score 10):

```
var string = "Mon 25-Jul-2011";
var parts = string.split(' ');
parts.shift(); // parts is modified to remove first word
var result;
if (parts instanceof Array) {
  result = parts.join(' ');
}
else {
  result = parts;
}
// result now contains all but the first word of the string.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate any dom, using their reference id, class or tag. Example

```
<div id="date">Mon 25-Jul-2011</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var strDate = $('#date').html();
   // Using regex, this will remove any day which may present in your date DOM
   strDate.replace(/(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat)/i, '');
   // This to trim any space present
   strDate.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
   $('#date').html(strDate);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
var line = "Mon 25-Jul-2011"; 
var edited = line.substring( line.indexOf(" ") + 1, line.length );
```

Comment: Sorry, too slow. Same as @Frédéric's answer, except slightly worse probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Mon 25-Jul-2011";
var firstSpace=str.indexOf(" ");
var newStr= str.slice(firstSpace);
//result:"25-Jul-2011"
```

Comment: @GowthamShiva There is no link.

Answer (score -1):

This should output  "25-Jul-2011":

```
var string = "Mon 25-Jul-2011"; 
string = string.split(' ').pop();
```

Comment: No, if I have something like "Stack Over Flow", it returns "Flow".

Comment: this is not a general case, as @FranciscoCorralesMorales mentioned